# Entity Framework code first with T4 template

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4.1, t4

I am going to create code-first view by using a T4 template like the below mentioned article says:

[Article here](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/06/13/entity-framework-codefirst-view-generation-templates-on-visual-studio-code-gallery/)

But it's causing an

> *run time exception*

like below. Why's that?

My connection string is configured properly in `App.config`.

My application is **N-Tier based**.So That **DbContext driven class is in Data Layer**.

This is **my connection String**:

```
<add name="PawLoyalty" connectionString="Server=.;database=PawLoyalty;Trusted_connection=true;pooling=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I am using EF 4.1 with vs 2010.

> *Running transformation: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation.*
>   *---> System.ArgumentException: The argument 'nameOrConnectionString' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space.*
>
> at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.RuntimeFailureMethods.ReportFailure(ContractFailureKind contractFailureKind, String userMessage, String conditionText,
>   Exception innerException)
>   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)
>   at PawLoyalty.Data.DataCatalog..ctor(Boolean allowLazyLoading) in D:\My Blog\Test
>   Projects\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty.Data\DataCatalog.cs:line 31
>   at PawLoyalty.Data.DataCatalog..ctor() in D:\My Blog\Test Projects\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty.Data\DataCatalog.cs:line 26
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
>   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark)
>   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
>   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingD6E95B37BD0790EBBCC7DB570AD3E2AC.GeneratedTextTransformation.GetEdmx(Type
>   contextType)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingD6E95B37BD0790EBBCC7DB570AD3E2AC.GeneratedTextTransformation.GenerateViews(String contextTypeName)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingD6E95B37BD0790EBBCC7DB570AD3E2AC.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.RunTransformation(TemplateProcessingSession
>   session, String source, ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, String&
>   result)

**Updated**

My **DbContext Derived class** looks like below.

```
 [Export(typeof(ISecurityDataCatalog))]
    [Export(typeof(IMappingDataCatalog))]
    [Export(typeof(IPawLoyaltyDataCatalog))]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public class DataCatalog : DbContext, IPawLoyaltyDataCatalog, ISecurityDataCatalog, IMappingDataCatalog
    {

        public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public static string AccountToken { get; set; }

        public DataCatalog()
            : this(false)
        {
        }

        public DataCatalog(bool allowLazyLoading = false)
            : base(ConnectionString)
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = allowLazyLoading;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ComplexType<DiscountValue>().Property(d => d.Fixed).HasPrecision(18, 2);
            modelBuilder.ComplexType<DiscountValue>().Property(d => d.Percentage).HasPrecision(18, 4);
            modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceFee>().Property(d => d.Fixed).HasPrecision(18, 2);
            modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceFee>().Property(d => d.Percentage).HasPrecision(18, 4);
            modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceFee>().Property(d => d.Total).HasPrecision(18, 4);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>().Property(d => d.Discount).HasPrecision(18, 2);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>().HasRequired(i => i.Appointment).WithOptional(a => a.Invoice).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceItem>().Property(d => d.Price).HasPrecision(18, 2);
            modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceItem>().Property(d => d.LatestTotal).HasPrecision(18, 2);
            modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceItem>().HasRequired(i => i.Allocation).WithOptional(a => a.InvoiceItem).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<InvoicePayment>().Property(d => d.Amount).HasPrecision(18, 4);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ServicePrice>().Property(d => d.Price).HasPrecision(18, 2);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceBreedPrice>().Property(d => d.Price).HasPrecision(18, 2);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProviderPolicy>().Property(d => d.SalesTax).HasPrecision(18, 4);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProviderCredit>().Property(d => d.Balance).HasPrecision(18, 2);
            modelBuilder.Entity<CombinedServiceDiscountDefinition>().HasRequired(c => c.PrimaryService).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<CombinedServiceDiscountDefinition>().HasRequired(c => c.SecondaryService).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<MedicalRecord>().HasRequired(m => m.Pet).WithOptional(p => p.Medical).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<BehavioralRecord>().HasRequired(b => b.Pet).WithOptional(p => p.Behavioral).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<DietRecord>().HasRequired(d => d.Pet).WithOptional(p => p.Diet).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Provider>().HasOptional(p => p.Profile).WithRequired(p => p.Provider).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProviderProfile>().HasOptional(p => p.Policy).WithRequired(p => p.Profile).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProviderProfile>().HasOptional(p => p.CustomerRequirements).WithRequired(p => p.Profile).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProviderProfile>().HasOptional(p => p.PaymentProfile).WithRequired(p => p.Profile).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Resource>().HasMany(r => r.Availability).WithRequired(a => a.Resource).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            Database.SetInitializer<DataCatalog>(null);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public const string ServiceKey = "PawLoyalty";

        public DbSet<StreetAddress> StreetAddresses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<InsuranceCarrier> InsuranceCarriers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PromotionCode> PromotionCodes { get; set; }

        // Provider Classes
        public DbSet<Provider> Providers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProviderProfile> ProviderProfiles { get; set; }
        //public DbSet<ProviderResourceItem> ProviderResourceItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Allocation> ResourceAllocations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ResourceAvailability> ResourceAvailabilities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Resource> Resources { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Wraps the object context detach method
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="t"></param>
        public void Detach<T>(T t) where T : class
        {
            // TODO: Is this needed? Hidden behind an interface in CTP5 implying infrequent usage.
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.Detach(t);
        }

        // Owner Classes
        public DbSet<MedicalRecordOrder> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Breed> Breeds { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PetProvider> PetProviders { get; set; }

        // Security Catalog Items
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        // Bing Maps Catalog items
        public DbSet<KnownLocation> KnownLocations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<KnownPostalCode> KnownPostalCodes { get; set; }

        public DbSet<QueuedEmail> QueuedEmails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<InvoicePayment> InvoicePayments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmailSubscription> EmailSubscriptions { get; set; }

        public DbSet<ResourceAvailabilityUpdate> ResourceAvailabilityUpdates { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmployeeAvailabilityUpdate> EmployeeAvailabilityUpdates { get; set; }
        public DbSet<InvoiceConfiguration> InvoiceConfigurations { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Vaccine> Vaccines { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TourEmail> TourEmails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ReservationRequest> ReservationRequest { get; set; }
        //public DbSet<ReservationRequestPets> ReservationRequestPets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Vaccination> Vaccinations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SpecialInstruction> SpecialInstructions { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<VendorStock> VendorStocks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ShoppingCart> ShoppingCarts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SaleDetail> SaleDetails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SalePayment> SalePayments { get; set; }

        public DbSet<PetService> PetServices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PetServicePrice> PetServicePrices { get; set; }

        public DbSet<MiscProperty> MiscProperties { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProviderMiscProperty> ProviderMiscProperties { get; set; }

        public DbSet<ProviderAuthorizedCreditCard> ProviderAuthorizedCreditCards { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AuthorizedCreditCard> AuthorizedCreditCards { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProviderPackage> ProviderPackages { get; set; }

        public DbSet<ProviderEmailPreference> ProviderEmailPreferences { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmailType> EmailTypes { get; set; }

        public DbSet<RetailSaleReturn> RetailSaleReturns { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ServiceRefund> ServiceRefunds { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: How does the parameterless ctor on the DbContext derived class look like.

Comment: @Pawel I have added my DbContext derived class.Please check that.I am having N-Tier application and T4 generated views in Data Layer (where DbContext derived class also in that layer).I put my conn string on application config file.

Comment: The issue is that your ConnectionString variable is never initialized and therefore is null when the template invokes the parameterless constructor. Just to see if stuff works you may want to set ConnectionString in the parmeterless ctor to `"Name=PawLoyalty"` to bind the connection string from the config to the context

Comment: I am also curious why you need to use pregenerated views? You don't seem to have that many entity types and entity sets so I don't think you will notice any noticeable difference in your start up code.

Comment: can you tell me where should I put "Name=PawLoyalty" ?

Comment: I was wrong. In addition I did not notice that ConnectionString was a static property so changing it may affect other instances. To be on the safe side I think you could do `base(ConnectionString ?? "Name=PawLoyalty")` - if the connection string has not been set use the one from the config file. Alternatively you may update the T4 template to set the connection string but it may be a bit cumbersome.

Comment: @Pawel Thanks for the grate support.It's working Now.Yes you're right.I did this as a R&D project.Our DbContext does not having large DbSets. Thanks again for your support.I got lot of information from your blog and it's very valuable comments.

Comment: Thanks. I am glad you found some interesting stuff on my blog.

Comment: @Pawel Hi,I am having 2 questions. 1. Please can you tell me what number of DbSets should be there to apply this Technic (roughly) ?   2. If we apply this for small one as a best practice will it degrade the performance ?

Comment: There is not a rigid rule since it depends not only on the number of the entities but also whether you are using inheritance, whether you have vertical keys vs. independent associations and how interconnected your model is. Unless you see a significant delay on startup you probably should not pre-generate views. Note that "significant" is relative here. Pregenerated views won't degrade the performance. Also, there are some improvements in EF6 which make view generation faster. Ideally people should not even have to know that EF is internally using views - it is just an implementation detail.

Comment: @Pawel OK thanks.It's clear. Currently we are unable to use EF 6.B'cos we are still using .Net 4.0 Framework.Another question is when we use Pre-generated views should we compile our view each time when we do change for the DbContext file (I mean model or db change) ?

Comment: EF6 works on both .NET Framework 4 and .NET Framework 4.5. The only difference between those is that when using .NET Framework 4 async is not supported - but you get all the features that were .NET Framework 4.5 exclusive in EF5 - enums, spatial, TVFs etc. EF6 alpha2 shipped yesterday (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/12/10/ef6-alpha-2-available-on-nuget.aspx). Yes you need to recreate views each time your model changes otherwise you will get an exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your invaluable information. May be final question for a while.That is first query execution (warm query) is a user specific one (browser dependent) or an application specific one(IIS Dependent) ? When any user executes query, is it available for all other users as cold query until IIS restart ?

Comment: EF does not know what the user is and is not aware of the environment it's being used in (IIS, ConsoleApp etc.) Queries are cached per app domain. In your context it means that after the query is cached all the users will use this cached query.

Comment: @Pawel Thanks for your grate support.It's Clear now for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

problem is DbContext Derived class's (DataCatalog) **parameter less constructor connection string issue.**

With support of **@Pawel** I have sorted out my problem.
You just need to give connection string for parameter less constructor as below.

```
 public class DataCatalog : DbContext
    {
        public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }

        public DataCatalog() : base(ConnectionString ?? "PawLoyalty")
        {

        }  
    }
```

**Note 1 :** If you're in separate layer (class library project) then you have to give your  connection string on **App.Config** file.

**Note 2 :** After doing all the changes you **have to compile** your project before run T4 template again

Hope this will help some one in future.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this only based your error code. Your error code says:

> The argument 'nameOrConnectionString' cannot be null, empty or contain
>   only white space.

So your `connection string` has mistake. Check your connection string in your `web config`. Be sure you connection string doesn't have white space.

Comment: Contains only white spaces doesn't mean contains any white spaces.

Comment: but with that connection string my system is working.Then what ?

Comment: I have added my conn with above question.Please see that.